# How to calculate likelihood to succeed knowing attempts and successful attempts amounts?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Say I have two algorithms that I don't know how they work but I know what they are meant to achieve. I tried algorithm A once and it succeeded. And tried algorithm B 100 times and succeeded 99 times. So A succeeded 100% times and B succeeded 99% times, but my common sense tells me B is still more "reliable" than A. How can I express this mathematically, or, how can I calculate which algorithm should I choose if I have to choose one when all I know about each of them is how many times it has been tested and how many times it succeeded (if it didn't that just means it failed for what I need)?

Please be as simple as possible I'm a newbie at math.

Comment: Wouldn't `(SuccessfulAttempts - 1) / Tries` be a good approximation?

Comment: ${\rm SuccessfulAttempts}/{\rm Tries}$ is a good approximation provided that ${\rm Tries}$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: I do the `-1` so that cases with small `Tries` don't get a very high number, so that, for example, `1 / 1` doesn't get 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is "Confidence Interval for Proportion". There are calculators for that online, see e.g. [this](http://www.dimensionresearch.com/resources/calculators/conf_prop.html) or [this](http://www.causascientia.org/math_stat/ProportionCI.html). [Here](http://www.dimensionresearch.com/resources/calculators/sample_size.html) is also a calculator that determines the minimum sample size you would need in order for your sample to meet the desired precision requirements for a study .